# cleartimeout in grep?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which is slimmed down for example purposes.  When I click my stop button the bExit flag is set to 1.  In the console the word clearing is repeated at 2 second intervals.  How do I clear the timeout so that the word clearing does not repeat itself?

```
//stop playback
$('.stop').live('click', function () {
    bExit = 1
    console.log("stopping...");
    clearTimeout(timer0);
});

var timer0;
var obj = $.grep(thedata, function (e, index) {
    timer0 = setTimeout(function () {
        if (bExit == 1) {
            console.log("clearing...");

            //$(".nodeCount,.statInfo,.theborder").hide();
            clearTimeout(timer0);

            return
        }
    }, 2000 * index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.setTimeout` and `window.clearTimeout` as noted in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Could it be because you are using a single variable `timer0` to store all the timers? What if you say `var timer0 = setTimeout(function () {`?